# Going back to last commit after soft reset and amend

Tags: git, git-reset, git-amend

I had 2 commits (local) and my history were : **A - B** :

- In commit A, the file **myfile_v1.txt**
- In commit B, multiple other files.
- In my working directory, I updated the file of the first commit with a small correction : **myfile_v2.txt**

I wanted to amend the commit A and replace the file in its new form in order to have a clean history before pushing anything.

I did this :

- `reset --soft` on A
- `add` **myfile_v2.txt**
- `commit --amend`

Now I can see that my commit A has the corrected file in it, but I cannot figure out how to go back in my previous HEAD nor if this is possible without committing B again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commits hash contains the full history of this commit. So if you change the history, the history does not belong to that commit anymore, but the commit has to be recreated.

There are many ways to do this. In your case you could just `cherry-pick` `B` and all is good.

How I would have done it is an interactive rebase (`rebase -i`). Either by first doing the interactive rebase, changing the stanza of `A` to `edit`, then doing the commit amending and then continuing rebasing. Or alternatively first create a new commit on top of `B` and then use `rebase -i` to reorder and `squash` or `fixup` the second commit. Or even using auto-fixup or auto-squash.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know the `cherry-pick` comand, very useful ! I'll try your other solution next time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a previous commit. Each commit is unique.

What you can do is to recreate the history with new commits. Using the command `git-rebase`

I understand that you are in this point now:

```
Pre_A - A - B
      \
       A1
```

You have lost your "B" Commit. To recover the commit use `git-reflog`

```
git reflog
```

You will see the latest position of the branch `HEAD`. One of them is the B commit. Write down the Hash of the beginning of the line. Example:

```
git reflog
  a123b Ammend Commit of Previous A that generates A1 commit
  b234c git reset soft to A Commit
  c345d B Commit
  b234c A Commit ##Look that the HASH is the same that the git-reset##
```

Once you have the HASH of the B Commit. Create a branch to recover the commit.

```
git branch tmpBranch c345d
```

At this point, what you need is to put this commit in the new history of "A1" instead of being in "A". You get this using `git-rebase`

I assumpt that you were working in your master branch.

```
git checkout tmpBranch
git rebase --onto master tmpBranch~1 tmpBranch
```

This recreate the history from one commit backward of tmpBranch commit until tmpBranch commit (in your case only one commit, The B commit) in master (that points to A1 commit).

Comment: This is kind of the long way around.  Upvoted for recommendation to use reflog, and pointing a temporary branch at a commit is a useful trick in general, so this would be better for recovering a larger number of commits.  For just one commit, a simple cherry-pick will be easier, though.

Comment: I resolved it with a cherry-pick, but thanks for the useful informations !

Comment: You are right. This case is simpler cherry-pick solution than mine. I focus on the part of `git-reflog` because I understood that it had been "lost" the B commit.

Comment: I agree that your `git-reflog` focus is welcome. It helped me to find the missing commit.